# DC/OS running a service on each agent

Tags: dcos

Is there any way of running a service (single instance) on each deployed agent node? I need that because each agent needs to mount a storage from S3 using `s3fs`

Comment: ATM not directly, no. But you can work around it like I did in https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/bb967625088902874d631eaa502573cb#file-install-vamp-09-sh-L21

Comment: That assumes you know the number of agents. What about scaling considerations?

Comment: Correct. See my script …

Comment: Oh...now I saw. I'm right guessing you enforce them from running multiple on the same agent by using `UNIQUE` constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the feature you're looking for is "daemon tasks", but unfortunately, it's still in the planning phase for Mesos itself. 
Due to the fact that schedulers don't know the entire state of the cluster, Mesos needs to add a feature to enable this functionality. Once in Mesos it can be integrated with DC/OS.

The primary workaround is to use Marathon to deploy an app with the UNIQUE constraint (`"constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]]`) and set the app `instances` to the number of agent nodes. Unfortunately this means you have to adjust the instances number when you add new nodes.

Comment: What if..I use `"constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]]` and the number to `9999`? :)

Comment: Having an arbitrarily large instance count technically works, but the app will always be in the deploying state, which isn't very efficient and may be confusing to operate.